# Problema con envío de correos masivos con PHpMailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

estoy enviando correos masivos a los usuarios registrados en una página Web, todo funciona bien, hasta que en el bucle encuentra un correo que no es válido, como tendría que hacer la validación en ese caso para que si el correo no es válido, no le haga caso y el bucle siga su curso.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'mail.dominio.com.pe';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'notificaciones@dominio.com.pe';
$mail->Password   = 'clave';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 465;

$recipients = $this -> model -> selectPropietariosCondominio($txtCondominioCom);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($recipients); $i++) { 
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('notificaciones@dominio.com.pe', 'Comunicado');
    $mail->addAddress($recipients[$i]['email'], $recipients[$i]['nombres']);

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $txtTituloCom;
    $mail->MsgHTML($txtCuerpoCom);
    $mail->send();
}
```

Los correos se envían bien, hasta que encuentra uno que no es válido.

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que un correo no es válido? ¿Es que en vez de ser @tudominio sea, por ejemplo, @gmail? ¿O es que el mail inválido es la respuesta del servidor? Pues, no se como obtienes los mails, ahí dice selectPropietariosEtc, si tus mails vienen de una consulta sql, podrías simplemente incluir los mails que sean con tu dominio. No trabajo mucho con php, de hecho poco y nada se de eso, pero antes de `$mail->addAddress` preguntaría si el mail cumple con el dominio, entonces que haga el `$mail->addAddress`. Seguro habrán más y mejores respuestas

Comment: Si dices que son emails de usuarios registrados en una web, significa que esos mails son válidos (pasaron por filtros y fueron validados para ser parte de dicha web) y si hay alguno que no es válido, créeme, tu problema no solo está en el envío de correos masivos.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que podemos ver, es problema del script porque, aunque un correo sea **prueba@ochoa.com** (nótese que el dominio no existe) el script debería funcionar.

Yo creo, y es mi pensar, que si sanitizas bien los correos, debería funcionar algo como lo siguiente: (PD: Esto lo hago en mis sistemas pero con una lógica diferente)

```
$recipients = $this -> model -> selectPropietariosCondominio($txtCondominioCom);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($recipients); $i++) {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $recipient = $recipients[$i]['nombres'];
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        $email = strtolower($dbm->escapeString($recipient));
        $sanitizedEmail = $helpers->sanitizeEmail($signupEmail);
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('notificaciones@dominio.com.pe', 'Comunicado');
        $mail->addAddress($sanitizedEmail, $recipient);

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $txtTituloCom;
        $mail->MsgHTML($txtCuerpoCom);
        $mail->send();
    }
}

/* Esto lo hago en mi DBM */
// Metodo para "Escapar" caracteres
public function escapeString($str){
    try {
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
        if (!$MySQLi) {
            throw new Exception('<br><b>Error escapeString Function</b>');
        }
        else{
            return $MySQLi->real_escape_string($str);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}

/* Esto en mi Helpers */
public function sanitizeEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}

public function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Al final he puesto la función `validateEmail()` pero esa yo no la usaría porque si un email no es válido entonces ahí si que se detendría el script. Aunque **aeportugal** ha puesto un `continue;` a mi no me convence.

Como dije, es una idea, habría que ver si algo así resuelve el problema o, por otro lado tener más contexto de los datos, por ejemplo, la línea donde pone `$recipients[$i]['nombres']` no me gusta nada, no soy de usar así las cosas, siento el código más desordenado, nada cuesta meterlo en una variable `$recipient = $recipients[$i]['nombres']` y eso supondría una mejor depuración de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices que un correo no es válido, ¿es que no tiene la forma requerida? `correo@dominio.com`?

De ser así, puede servir un [filtro](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php):

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($recipients); $i++) { 
    $email = $recipients[$i]['email'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Error, el correo '$email' no es valido" . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('notificaciones@dominio.com.pe', 'Comunicado');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $recipients[$i]['nombres']);
    // ...
```

Comment: Sucede que mi cliente manejaba sus registros por excel, entonces cuando ya lo estoy haciendo en una aplicación web, he subido los datos que ellos tienen registrados (sin filtro, ni validaciones), ahí cuando recorre el bucle, hay correos que no existen, tienen el formato correcto (nombre@dominio.com) pero no existen y ahí el bucle se para y manda error 500, pero a los correos anteriores a ese, si manda el correo.

Comment: He visto en las páginas que hacen envíos masivos, que luego que envía a la lista de correos te dice a que correos no se pudo enviar, entonces necesito saber si con PHPMailer se puede hacer una validación de ese tipo. Quizás podría ser hacer una pregunta a $mail -> send();    Voy a probar

Comment: Que raro, cuando yo uso `PHPMailer` si un correo no existe (de los que uso de prueba como prueba@ochoa.com) no tengo problemas en el código, donde salta una alerta es el el correo desde donde yo hago los envíos. Lo que quiero decir es que nunca había visto que `PHPMailer` valide que el correo exista y reciba el correo. @aeportugal, alguna vez le ha pasado así?

Comment: @OCHOA es correcto. También envío correos masivos con phpmailer y el script no se cierra hasta que termina independientemente si los correos existen, o no, o tengan problemas. Toca entonces revisar la bandeja de entrada del correo que envía, verificar los rebotes y poder filtrarlos.